# XAMPP - Permissions issue for table 'C:\xampp\tmp\#sql3a10_4_4.MAI'

Tags: php, mysql, xampp, mariadb

I am sorry if this question has already been asked but I have not been able to find the solution, for this i rephrase the question:

I installed the XAMPP version 3.2.3 (PHP 7.2.18) on my PC with Windows 10.
Once the installation was finished I imported my website built with Magento 1.9.4.3 and finally I imported the database into phpmyadmin.
So far so good and in fact by launching the address "localhost/miosito/" on my browser I regularly see the site.

The problem arises when I try to navigate through the categories of the site because I get this error every time:

```
    a:5:{i:0;s:1638:"SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 6 Error on delete of 'C:\xampp\tmp\#sql3a10_4_4.MAI' (Errcode: 13 "Permission denied"), query was: SELECT `attr_table`.* FROM `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `attr_table`
     INNER JOIN `eav_entity_attribute` AS `set_table` ON attr_table.attribute_id = set_table.attribute_id AND set_table.attribute_set_id = '4' WHERE (attr_table.entity_id = '15726') AND (attr_table.store_id IN (0, 1)) UNION ALL SELECT `attr_table`.* FROM `catalog_product_entity_decimal` AS `attr_table`
     INNER JOIN `eav_entity_attribute` AS `set_table` ON attr_table.attribute_id = set_table.attribute_id AND set_table.attribute_set_id = '4' WHERE (attr_table.entity_id = '15726') AND (attr_table.store_id IN (0, 1)) UNION ALL SELECT `attr_table`.* FROM `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `attr_table`
     INNER JOIN `eav_entity_attribute` AS `set_table` ON attr_table.attribute_id = set_table.attribute_id AND set_table.attribute_set_id = '4' WHERE (attr_table.entity_id = '15726') AND (attr_table.store_id IN (0, 1)) UNION ALL SELECT `attr_table`.* FROM `catalog_product_entity_text` AS `attr_table`
     INNER JOIN `eav_entity_attribute` AS `set_table` ON attr_table.attribute_id = set_table.attribute_id AND set_table.attribute_set_id = '4' WHERE (attr_table.entity_id = '15726') AND (attr_table.store_id IN (0, 1)) UNION ALL SELECT `attr_table`.* FROM `catalog_product_entity_datetime` AS `attr_table`
     INNER JOIN `eav_entity_attribute` AS `set_table` ON attr_table.attribute_id = set_table.attribute_id AND set_table.attribute_set_id = '4' WHERE (attr_table.entity_id = '15726') AND (attr_table.store_id IN (0, 1)) ORDER BY `store_id` ASC";i:1;s:5397:"#0
```

Or sometimes this error occurs

```
    a:5:{i:0;s:1640:"SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 6 Error on delete of 'C:\xampp\tmp\#sql3a10_3_125.MAI' (Errcode: 13 "Permission denied"), query was: SELECT `attr_table`.* FROM `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `attr_table`
     INNER JOIN `eav_entity_attribute` AS `set_table` ON attr_table.attribute_id = set_table.attribute_id AND set_table.attribute_set_id = '4' WHERE (attr_table.entity_id = '15914') AND (attr_table.store_id IN (0, 1)) UNION ALL SELECT `attr_table`.* FROM `catalog_product_entity_decimal` AS `attr_table`
     INNER JOIN `eav_entity_attribute` AS `set_table` ON attr_table.attribute_id = set_table.attribute_id AND set_table.attribute_set_id = '4' WHERE (attr_table.entity_id = '15914') AND (attr_table.store_id IN (0, 1)) UNION ALL SELECT `attr_table`.* FROM `catalog_product_entity_int` AS `attr_table`
     INNER JOIN `eav_entity_attribute` AS `set_table` ON attr_table.attribute_id = set_table.attribute_id AND set_table.attribute_set_id = '4' WHERE (attr_table.entity_id = '15914') AND (attr_table.store_id IN (0, 1)) UNION ALL SELECT `attr_table`.* FROM `catalog_product_entity_text` AS `attr_table`
     INNER JOIN `eav_entity_attribute` AS `set_table` ON attr_table.attribute_id = set_table.attribute_id AND set_table.attribute_set_id = '4' WHERE (attr_table.entity_id = '15914') AND (attr_table.store_id IN (0, 1)) UNION ALL SELECT `attr_table`.* FROM `catalog_product_entity_datetime` AS `attr_table`
     INNER JOIN `eav_entity_attribute` AS `set_table` ON attr_table.attribute_id = set_table.attribute_id AND set_table.attribute_set_id = '4' WHERE (attr_table.entity_id = '15914') AND (attr_table.store_id IN (0, 1)) ORDER BY `store_id` ASC";i:1;s:5397:"#0
```

The attempts I made to correct the problem so far are these:

1. I have given full privileges on all databases to all users
   present in xampp's phpmyadmin
2. To the folder C://xampp/ I have assigned full privileges to each
   user of the PC both for reading and for writing
3. I tried to empty the C://xampp/tmp/ folder by turning off XAMPP
   and then turning it back on
4. I also tried to set innodb_force_recovery = 0 /
   innodb_force_recovery = 1 / innodb_force_recovery = 6 because I had
   read that it was used to solve the problem in question

Unfortunately none of these served to solve the problem.
How could I do?

Thanks for any help

Comment: "I imported my website". That's too vague. If you just copied the raw database files, you certainly broke it. If you did a proper SQL dump and import, did you copy users and permissions?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález When i installed xampp i copied entire folder of my magento website inside C://xampp/htdocs. After this i assigned to the user of my pc full permissions for read and write the entire directory C://xampp/ and i assigned full permission to the user root of localhost. Finally, i imported entire database of my magento website with success.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `xampp/tmp` find `#sql30a0_3b_793` and click on properties.
Give `write` property to all users